# how to read file.cfg line by line and put it in the textbox

Tags: c#

I want to display the contents of the file.
and i tried, it run. but not i want.

my file are like this

```
a="1"
b="2"
c="3"
```

```
lines=lines ?? File.ReadAllLines("D:\\file.cfg");
if(index < lines.length)
textbox1.Text = lines[index++);
textboxt2.Text=lines[index++];
textbox3.Text=lines[index++];
```

i expect the out put is '1' , '2' or '3'. but the actual output is a="1" ,b="2" and c="3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\file.cfg");    
            if (index < lines.Length)    
            {     
                textbox1.Text = new String(lines[index++].Where(x => Char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray());    
                textboxt2.Text = new String(lines[index++].Where(x => Char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray());    
                textbox3.Text = new String(lines[index++].Where(x => Char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray());        
            }
```

Comment: very nice and clean.  Love this solution. But difficult for new people to C#. But it is Great.

Comment: dude, how i make this code read file dinamic? i mean,  i can choose the file what i want.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a very basic example using very basic C# syntax.  I am assuming you are new to c# so this would be simpler to understand. C# has many advance expressions to make solutions to parsing extremely small but very difficult to understand for someone only knowing a small amount of c#. so here is a simple example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Readand_display
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Example2();
            Example1();
        }

        private static void Example2()
        {
            string TextBox1 = null;
            string TextBox2 = null;
            string TextBox3 = null;

            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.cfg");
            char[] delimiter = { '=', '"' };

            if (lines.Count()>0)
            {
                 TextBox1 = lines[0].Split(delimiter)[2];
                 TextBox2 = lines[1].Split(delimiter)[2];
                 TextBox3 = lines[2].Split(delimiter)[2];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("TextBox1 = {0}, TextBox2 = {1}, TextBox3 = {2}", TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3); // show all the values in the line separated by comma
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        private static void Example1()
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.cfg");
            char[] delimiter = { '=', '"' };

            List<string> values = new List<string>();    // To store the values 1,2,3 
            foreach (var item in lines)
            {
                List<string> line = item.Split(delimiter).ToList();
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", line[0], line[1], line[2]); // show all the values in the line separated by comma
                values.Add(line[2]);
            }

            foreach (var item in values)  // this is just to show your the values.
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);    // show just the 1,2,3 values
            }

            /*****************************
             *  HERE YOU WOULD ASSIGN THE VALUES TO WHAT EVER OBJECT TYOU LIKE.
             *  FOR EXAMPLE
             *  "textbox1.text = values[0];
             *  "textbox2.text = values[1];
             *  "textbox3.text = values[2];
             *  ******************************/
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code loops through each line from the file. It splits each line on the equals sign (=). All we are interested in is the second element of the resulting array. The second element which is index 1 is then trimmed of the double quotes and added to the list. The elements of the list are then displayed in the text boxes.

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\\file.cfg");
        List<string> TextBoxValues = new List<string>();
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
           var stringParts = line.Split('=');
            TextBoxValues.Add(stringParts[1].Trim('"'));
        }
        textBox1.Text = TextBoxValues[0];
        textBox2.Text = TextBoxValues[1];
        textBox3.Text = TextBoxValues[2];
    }
```